# How to make a bar graph in Shiny that relies on checkboxGroupInput to graph specific values

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a shiny app that displays different variables of the "Cut" variable (Fair, good, very good...) in a bar graph. I am not totally sure how to do it using the checkboxGroupInput function. I pretty much want it so that if the user selects fair, good, and very good, the bar graph will display only those values. This is my first week with R, any help would be much appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
jewl <- diamonds

# User interface ----
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Diamonds Information"),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  helpText("Choose a Cut to Examine"),

  checkboxGroupInput("vars", "What cuts would you like to display?", choices = c("Fair", 
                                                                            "Good",
                                                                            "Very Good", 
                                                                            "Premium",
                                                                            "Ideal", "All"), 
                     selected = "All"
                     )
),

mainPanel(plotOutput("plot")

)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {


output$plot <- renderPlot({
if (input$vars == "All"){
  newdata <- group_by(diamonds, cut)
newdata2 <- summarize(newdata, avg = mean(price))
ggplot(data = newdata2) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = avg))}

#WANT TO ADD SOMETHING HERE

 })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset your `newdata2` to get only those variables selected like this:

```
# 'which' function does a comparison and returns the indexes
# which meets the conditions (check the subset_ids to see that is a vector of integers (the indexes)
subset_ids <- which(newdata2$cut %in% c('Fair', 'Premium'))

# now, you use your ids to subset the data.frame
# a data.frame can be subsetted like this
# data.frame[rows, columns] (you can leave blank for no subsetting)
newdata3 <- newdata2[subset_ids, ]

# OBS: Columns can be selected by numbers or its name
```

So in your code you can do like this

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (input$vars == "All"){
      newdata <- group_by(diamonds, cut)
      newdata2 <- summarize(newdata, avg = mean(price))
      ggplot(data = newdata2) +
        geom_col(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = avg))
    }
    else {
      newdata <- group_by(diamonds, cut)
      newdata2 <- summarize(newdata, avg = mean(price))
      ggplot(data = newdata2[which(newdata2$cut %in% input$vars),]) +
        geom_col(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = avg))
    }

  })
}
```

Which will cause some warnings, but solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was really frustrating me. If you may, can you super briefly go over that command you gave me? I am having some trouble understanding why it works

Comment: The subsetting of your data or the shiny part?

Comment: Sorry, how the data was subsetted.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot!